# How can I generate ID with Prefix, Numeric Number and suffix?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to generate an ID in MSSQL Server 2008. Which will be Prefix + Numeric Number + suffix Like 'PV#000001#SV'. Which will be user defined (depends on configuration ) prefix, numeric length, suffix and starting number. Numeric number will be increased every time.

I tied to write this :

> Blockquote
>   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spACC_SELECT_VOUCHER_NUMBER]
>
> ```
>  @COMPANY_ID uniqueidentifier,
>  @VOUCHER_TYPE INT
> ```
>
> AS BEGIN
>
> DECLARE @IS_AUTOMETIC BIT = (SELECT VOUCHER_CONFIG_NUMBERING_METHOD
>   FROM ACC_VOUCHER_CONFIG WHERE
>   ACC_VOUCHER_CONFIG.VOUCHER_CONFIG_VALUE=@VOUCHER_TYPE  )
>
> ```
> IF(@IS_AUTOMETIC=1)
>     BEGIN
>         SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(V.VOUCHER_CODE, 7, 23) IS NULL  
>                     THEN CASE WHEN VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_PREFIX IS NULL THEN '' ELSE VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_PREFIX END + 
>                             RIGHT ('0000000000000'+ CAST( VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_BEGINING_NUMBER AS VARCHAR), VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_NUMERIC_WIDTH) + 
>                             CASE WHEN VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_SUFFIX IS NULL THEN '' ELSE VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_SUFFIX END
>                     ELSE CASE WHEN VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_PREFIX IS NULL THEN '' ELSE VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_PREFIX END + 
>                             RIGHT ('0000000000000'+ CAST((CAST( SUBSTRING(V.VOUCHER_CODE, 7, 23) AS INT)+1) AS VARCHAR), VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_NUMERIC_WIDTH) +  
>                             CASE WHEN VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_SUFFIX IS NULL THEN '' ELSE VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_SUFFIX END
>                     END AS VOUCHER_CODE FROM  ACC_VOUCHER_CONFIG VC
>                     LEFT OUTER JOIN  ACC_VOUCHER V ON  VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_VALUE =  V.VOUCHER_TYPE                        
>                     WHERE  VC.COMPANY_ID=@COMPANY_ID AND VC.VOUCHER_CONFIG_VALUE=@VOUCHER_TYPE      
> END
> ```
>
> END

When I change the numeric length / suffix its not working.

Thanks
Nahid

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is you problem? Not really sure what you're having problem with...

Comment: My problem when I change the numeric length its not working.

Answer (score 4):

For the six-digit number you're struggling with, add leading zeroes like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,Num),6) AS NUM FROM your_table
```

Where `Num` is your sequential number.

This prepends 5 zeroes and then takes the right 6 characters from the resulting string.

A more detailed writeup of custom ID generation is here:

- http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to store just a number in the database (i.e. an int) and format the ID client side with tools that are better suited for it (i.e. a programming language that has sprintf or equivalent string formatting).